# Pyside6: prevent QGroupBox getting smaller when added to a QScrollArea

Tags: python, qt, pyside6, qscrollarea, qgroupbox

I am trying to add some group-boxes containing some other widgets to a scroll area (which has a vertical layout in a QWidget). But when I click the button several times to add new group-boxes, they just get smaller and smaller.

Adding one rule:

[image: Adding one rule]

Adding three rules:

[image: Adding three rules]

Adding a lot of rules:

[image: Adding a lot of Rules]

Here is the code I am using to add the group-boxes to the scroll area:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from views.Ui_form import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindowForm(QWidget, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.anadir_regla.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.eliminar_regla.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        n = 1
        if self.anadir_regla.clicked == True:
            n = n + 1
        #top_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    #def sum_c(num):
    #    return sum(int(c) for c in num if c.isdecimal())

    
    def add(self, n): #funcion para añadir
        Regla = QGroupBox()
        Regla.setObjectName(u"Regla")
        Regla.setTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Regla "+str(n), None))
        Regla.setGeometry(QRect(0, 10, 791, 80))
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(Regla)

        #Frame interno de las reglas

        combo_objeto = QComboBox(self.Regla)
        combo_objeto.setObjectName(u"combo_objeto")
        combo_objeto.setGeometry(QRect(10, 20, 151, 22))
        combo_objeto.setMaxVisibleItems(2)
        combo_objeto.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Elije un Objeto", None))
        layout.addWidget(combo_objeto)

        id_objeto = QLineEdit(self.Regla)
        id_objeto.setObjectName(u"id_objeto")
        id_objeto.setGeometry(QRect(190, 20, 161, 22))
        layout.addWidget(id_objeto)

        combo_accion = QComboBox(self.Regla)
        combo_accion.setObjectName(u"combo_accion")
        combo_accion.setGeometry(QRect(380, 20, 141, 22))
        layout.addWidget(combo_accion)

        combo_resultado = QComboBox(self.Regla)
        combo_resultado.setObjectName(u"combo_resultado")
        combo_resultado.setGeometry(QRect(540, 20, 141, 22))
        layout.addWidget(combo_resultado)
        
        self.lay_reglas.addWidget(Regla)
        self.top_widget = (self.lay_reglas)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.top_widget)
     
    def delete(self): #eliminar Reglas
        count = self.lay_reglas.count()
        item = self.lay_reglas.itemAt(count - 1)
        widget = item.widget()
        widget.deleteLater()
```

PS: The adding and deleting buttons work fine.

Comment: What is it you expect to happen instead?

Comment: I was hoping that the QGroupBox would not lose its size while the scroll would work.

Comment: @Yoseph_Reyes If you want the group box to have a specific height, use `setFixedHeight()`. The real question is: why do you need it to be *that* big? Note: this is not an *error*. It might not be the behavior you expect, but an *error* is a very different thing. I know that English is not your primary language, but some terms are very specific.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue from the description? What button is getting smaller and smaller?

Comment: @Yoseph_Reyes  That can all be easily adjusted though padding and margin in QStyleSheets as well.

Comment: @LászlóPapp  The OP wants to add more rows of groupboxes without making all the space surrounding them get smaller.  Instead he wants the page size to increase and the scrollbar handle to shrink

Comment: I do not follow.

Comment: @musicamante how do i name this "question"? to make it more accurate

Comment: @Yoseph_Reyes The third image in your question looks correct. What you really need is to do is add an expanding spacer to the end of the layout, so that it pushes all the group-boxes together. If you want the group-boxes to be bigger, give them a minimum height (and note that setting the geometry will have no effect, since the layout will ignore it).

Comment: @Yoseph_Reyes PS: please add the `Ui_MainWindow` class to the code in your question,